# Starting redmine in a new port

Tags: port, redmine, bitnami

I am currently using **Redmine 3.3.0-1** in windows downloaded via **Bitnami Redmine Installer**. Currently the application is launching in port 81. How do I change this to some other port ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redmine is offered through Apache when using the Bitnami Redmine Stack. Indeed, there are a couple of "thin" services running on ports 3001 and 3002 and Apache redirect the web requests to those ports. Therefore, it's enough to you to change the Apache port.

Here you have a guide that explains how to do so:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/components/apache/#how-to-change-the-apache-port